# Monitor the status of Runspace Pool from a different Runspace session

Tags: powershell, runspace

I am working on a GUI Wizard, this GUI Wizard will collect information from the user regarding his environment and then at the last page the tool will call 28 subscripts in a Runspace Pool.

I want to monitor the status of the 28 subscripts from a different runspace, as if I monitor the status within the GUI runspace, the GUI will freeze. The problem is when I add the Async variable to the SyncHash table and pass it to another runspace, the status will all be completed equal true.

Do you have any idea on how to monitor the status of a runspace pool from a different runspace and take actions once the status of all 28 subscripts is completed as true.

```
            #   Create RunspacePool.
            $RunspacePool = [RunspaceFactory]::CreateRunspacePool(1, [int]$env:NUMBER_OF_PROCESSORS + 1, $InitialSessionState, $Host)   #   Create Runspace Pool and add InitialSessionState to it
            $RunspacePool.ApartmentState = "MTA"  # Set Runspace Pool ApartmentState
            $RunspacePool.Open()    #   Open Runspace Pool
            $PSSessions = @()   #   Create an Array to add all PowerShell Session to it to use it when closing the sessions.

            #   Run a ForEach loop on all Subscript files and whith each iteration create a powershell session and call subscript.
            ForEach ($SubScript in $GuiHash.SubscriptFilePath) {
                $PowerShellSession = [powershell]::Create()
                $PowerShellSession.RunspacePool = $RunspacePool
                $AsyncHandle = $PowerShellSession.AddScript($SubScript).BeginInvoke()
                $PSSessions += [PSCustomObject] @{ 
                    Session = $PowerShellSession
                    Invoke = $AsyncHandle
                }
            }
```

This is the output of the Async Varibale form the other runspace showing all as true

```
PS C:\Users\Administrator> Debug-Runspace  Runspace103
Debugging Runspace: Runspace103
To end the debugging session type the 'Detach' command at the debugger prompt, or type 'Ctrl+C' otherwise.

Stopped at: $Completed = ($GuiHash.PSSessions | Where-Object {$_.Invoke.IsCompleted -Eq $True}).Count
[DBG]: [Process:9212]: [Runspace103]: PS C:\Users\Administrator>> $GuiHash.PSSessions.invoke

CompletedSynchronously IsCompleted AsyncState AsyncWaitHandle                  
---------------------- ----------- ---------- ---------------                  
                 False        True            System.Threading.ManualResetEvent
                 False        True            System.Threading.ManualResetEvent
                 False        True            System.Threading.ManualResetEvent
                 False        True            System.Threading.ManualResetEvent
                 False        True            System.Threading.ManualResetEvent
                 False        True            System.Threading.ManualResetEvent
                 False        True            System.Threading.ManualResetEvent
                 False        True            System.Threading.ManualResetEvent
                 False        True            System.Threading.ManualResetEvent
                 False        True            System.Threading.ManualResetEvent
                 False        True            System.Threading.ManualResetEvent
                 False        True            System.Threading.ManualResetEvent
                 False        True            System.Threading.ManualResetEvent
                 False        True            System.Threading.ManualResetEvent
                 False        True            System.Threading.ManualResetEvent
                 False        True            System.Threading.ManualResetEvent
                 False        True            System.Threading.ManualResetEvent
                 False        True            System.Threading.ManualResetEvent
                 False        True            System.Threading.ManualResetEvent
                 False        True            System.Threading.ManualResetEvent
                 False        True            System.Threading.ManualResetEvent
                 False        True            System.Threading.ManualResetEvent
                 False        True            System.Threading.ManualResetEvent
                 False        True            System.Threading.ManualResetEvent
                 False        True            System.Threading.ManualResetEvent
                 False        True            System.Threading.ManualResetEvent
                 False        True            System.Threading.ManualResetEvent
                 False        True            System.Threading.ManualResetEvent



[DBG]: [Process:9212]: [Runspace103]: PS C:\Users\Administrator>> detach
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I have handled what you're trying to do before, adapted for your needs:

```
$PowerShellSession = @()
$Jobs = @()
$Wait = @()

#Loop through online servers for this DC and create a process for each to patch that server (up to 10 at a time)
For($i = 0; $i -lt $GuiHash.SubscriptFilePath.Count; $i++){
    #Create scriptblock from file
    $SB = [scriptblock]::Create((Get-Content $GuiHash.SubscriptFilePath[$i]))
    #Create thread for server
    $PowerShellSession += [powershell]::Create()
    #Add the scripblock to be run in the thread
    $PowerShellSession[$i].AddScript($SB)|Out-Null
    #Assign the runspace pool to this runspace 
    $PowerShellSession[$i].RunspacePool = $RunSpacePool
    #Start the script within its runspace as ASync
    $Jobs += $PowerShellSession[$i].BeginInvoke()
    #Find its wait handle to track the job
    $Wait += $jobs[$i].AsyncWaitHandle
}

#Wait for all jobs to complete
If($Wait){[System.Threading.WaitHandle]::WaitAll($Wait)|Out-Null}

#Collect the jobs
$Results = For($i = 0; $i -lt $Jobs.count;$i++){
    $PowerShellSession[$i].EndInvoke($Jobs[$i])
}
```

The main difference is that I capture what you assign as `$Asynchandle`'s `.AsyncWaitHandle` property for each thread in an array, then tell PowerShell to wait for all of the wait handles to complete.